# pgAdmin goes "out of memory" with large queries

Tags: postgresql, memory, pgadmin

I am trying to run query with results stored in file from PostgreSQL. Now I am trying to use pgAdmin for this task: running query to file option.
Problem starts with large queries. When I try running query which result set is around 3GB pgAdmin returns "out of memory" error.

Any idea how to extend pgAdmin memory pool? (I have still few gigs of unused memory on machine.)
Or maybe there is another way I can store large result set in a csv file?

I am using pgAdmin 1.16 with PostgreSQL 9.2.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit.

Comment: A 32bit process can't allocate more than approx. 3gb of memory. You will need to use the 64bit version if you need more memory for pgAdmin

Comment: Have you tried using the [latest version pgAdmin 1.18.1?](http://pgadmin.org/)